# How to align baselines for absolutely positioned HTML element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use CSS to write a short label inside the margin of an HTML paragraph, in a similar way to how HTML list items are labeled.  The way I thought I'd do this was make the label an absolutely positioned inline-block which is shifted inside the margin (see HTML+CSS code below).  This works as I expected, except I can't find a way to align the baseline of the label's text with the corresponding paragraph's first line.

HTML+CSS code:

```css
.labeled {
  margin-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.labeled::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(data-label);
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  left: -40px;
  /* How to vertically position so paragraph and label have same baseline? */
}
```

```html
<p class="labeled" data-label="L">Lorem ipsum<sup>SUPERSCRIPT</sup> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut cursus sem in nisl pulvinar porta. Praesent laoreet nisl sit amet sagittis mollis. Aliquam sit amet erat vitae enim ullamcorper dapibus ut vel lectus. Maecenas facilisis
  accumsan diam ut maximus. Suspendisse potenti. Donec sapien sem, lacinia eu eros vitae, tincidunt congue leo.
</p>
```

[The same code in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qf9ko78y/3/)

The problem is that the label is vertically aligned with the first line of the paragraph at top, not at baseline as I would want them to be:

[image: screenshot of HTML code output]

The two ‘L’ in the picture above would be vertically aligned if it were not for the superscript making the first line higher.

How can I achieve the same result but with correct vertical alignment?  (I'm willing to do things differently, and I'm willing to assume that the label will never always fit inside one line of the margin; I'm also OK with the label being right-aligned inside the margin instead of left-aligned, if that helps in any way.  On the other hand, I don't want to use any sort of JavaScript, and I'd like to avoid ugly hacks.  Am I asking for too much?)

Comment: Keep in mind `position:absolute` removes the element from the documents normal flow, therefore you are going to lose the ability to align to any baseline or anything by reference.  Absolutely positioned elements will , by default, align to the top. You will most likely need to adjust the `top` property manually.

Comment: A great article on [***line-height*** versus ***line-box***](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align) in terms of css and text, I think you will find Temani's answer much more adaptive to your needs than trying to figure out the proper base-line on an element that is not within the docs normal flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

get rid of `position:absolute` and use negative margin

```css
.labeled {
  margin-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.labeled::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(data-label);
  width: 40px;
  margin-left:-40px;
}
```

```html
<p class="labeled" data-label="L">Lorem ipsum<sup>SUPERSCRIPT</sup> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut cursus sem in nisl pulvinar porta. Praesent laoreet nisl sit amet sagittis mollis. Aliquam sit amet erat vitae enim ullamcorper dapibus ut vel lectus. Maecenas facilisis
  accumsan diam ut maximus. Suspendisse potenti. Donec sapien sem, lacinia eu eros vitae, tincidunt congue leo.
</p>
```